# Send data through Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

There is ListView and it has to send data to another Activity after item clicked

This is sending data:

```
listFavorites.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ListWords.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, Long.toString(id));
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

And this is getting data:

```
  public Fragment getItem(int id) {
       if(id>=0&&getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)==null) {
           return PageFragment.newInstance(id);
       }else if(id==0&&getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)!=null){
           int drinkID = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
           return PageFragment.newInstance(drinkID);}
        else{
           return PageFragment.newInstance(id);
       }
```

This part is working fine: if(id==0&&getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)!=null)

But here it won't checks for null:
getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)==null

it appears errors as 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Thanx in advance, I appreciate any help, advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
if(intent.getExtras()!=null)
{    
   if(id>=0&&intent.getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)==null) {
       return PageFragment.newInstance(id);
   }else if(id==0&&intent.getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)!=null){
       int drinkID = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
       return PageFragment.newInstance(drinkID);}
    else{
       return PageFragment.newInstance(id);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot, could you explain me what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you converted a long value to String, it cannot be null since the values of the long is predefine with the item list showing.

Comment: thx for quick response, I wrote intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, (int) id);    But it still get error

Comment: The id is a long so you are downcast a bigger value to a small value which might be the problem. Just remove the (int) cast.

Comment: But when debug the code it returns id, and also this part   if(id==0&&getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)!=null)     is working well

Comment: So what is the main issue now so that we can resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first try would be to refactor that if block so it could be more efficient :

```
if(id==0&&getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE)!=null)
{
    int drinkID = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    return PageFragment.newInstance(drinkID);
}
else
{
    return PageFragment.newInstance(id);
}
```

Why, you may ask? Because if we check the result of the first and third if statement, you are returning the exact same thing, so the first if-block is useless. Now, this way it's more efficient and you are removing the if-statement that technically was never evaluated.

Comment: thx for quick response. You see I have two way to send data: first one through Intent, as I wrote, second is by id -> PageFragment.newInstance(int id)......first is when I click item, second when app is launched it has to show me firstPage as an id=1..so id might be equal to 2,3,4,5, as page swiping......anyway, the answer of Mansoor is helped, now it's working, but it takes long time, maybe I should reduce some useless code,lol